# How to get the new value added to a cookie without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, cookies

I have this PHP code :

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['go'])){
     echo 'the array contains' . $_COOKIE['arrayCount'] . 'values';
  }
?>
<form method='POST'>;
  <?php
    $arr = array(//some dynamic values);
    setcookie('arrayCount' , count($arr));
  ?>
  <input type='submit' name='go' />
</form>
```

for example if the count of the value in the array is '10'  , and the previous count was '15' , I get the '15' printed with the message:
'the array contains 15 values'

I want to print the message at the top of the page , Is it possible to be done this way or I would need to use Ajax or re arrange the code?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you have output clash. You should always put your setcookie BEFORE any echo or output.

Comment: I am not sure I am following. You can print the cookie value anywhere, provided you set it before any output.

Comment: cookies are sent with http header you cannot set cookie after you closed the header

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), not with PHP.

> This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any
>   output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.

However, you can get it on the next page load.

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page
>   load with the $_COOKIE array. Cookie values may also exist in
>   $_REQUEST.

However, [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) has great information on how to do it with Javascript.